# How to split the two strings using filetype.split?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file

I have got a string as follows:

```
string name ="C:\folder\back-201190082233.zip";
```

How can I get only the part `201190082233` from the string `name`? I have tried like this for getting the only the part `201190082233`

```
string filetype = name;
string[] getfiledate = filetype.Split('-');
```

But I am getting the part `201190082233.zip`. Now I want to get only the part `201190082233`. Would anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string name = "C:\folder\back-201190082233.zip";
string filetype = name;
string[] getfiledate = filetype.Split(new[] {'.', '-'});
string datepart = getfiledate[1];
```

Comment: @errorcode105 see my edit. not sure why you are trying to split on `'-'`.

Comment: i am very sorry this is correct format thats why i am splitting with '-' this is teh correct string "C:\folder\back-201190082233.zip";

Comment: hi i have another doubt how can get only this 20119008 from 201190082233  would you pls give syggest any solution for this

Comment: @errorcode105 if you are trying to get the first 8 chars, you can do `var first8char = datepart.Substring(0, 8);`

Comment: what about this path - "C:\my.folder\back-201190082233.zip" ?

Comment: @Bala Many thanks i have upvoted you but dont know other person has down voted , is there any possible to upvote ...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a good idea to use regular expressions:

```
var match = Regex.Match("back.201190082233.zip" , @"(?<=-)\d+(?=\.)");
if(match.Success)
{
    var numericPart = match.Value;
}
```

Edit:

If you're dealing with paths, .Net offers help:

```
string name = @"C:\folder\back.201190082233.zip";
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(name);
var match = Regex.Match(fileName , @"(?<=-)\d+(?=\.)");
if(match.Success)
{
    var numericPart = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: Then someone decides to write dates in another way, like this: `back.2011dec24.zip`.

Comment: @FilipEkberg i am sorry cant change the name like you specified

Comment: @errorcode105, I didn't mean it like that. It was a joke.
Spenders code is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this way?

```
var fileDate= filetype.Split('.')[1];
```

**Edit for updates**

```
var fileDate = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filetype).Split('.')[0]
```

Comment: i am very sorry this is correct format thats why i am splitting with '-' this is the correct string "C:\folder\back-201190082233.zip";

Comment: So just use .Split('-') instead of '.'

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```
var date = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( name ).Split('-')[1];
```

would be sufficient.

See documentation for function [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

Comment: i am very sorry this is correct format this is the correct string "C:\folder\back-201190082233.zip";

Answer (score 0):

Why are you splitting with a '-' ?  Shouldn't it be '.' ?

```
string numberPart = filetype.Split('.')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like below

```
string str = name.Split(".")[1];
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

or if the string changes you could use a mor specific regular expression like this:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("back.201190082233.zip", @"[^\.]+\.([^\.]+)\..*", "$1");
```